# how to use Get-ChildItem to search sub keys including current key

Tags: powershell

How do I use Get-ChildItem to search sub keys including current key of my $path in the registry? I am searching data column/part of a value for a specific string. My current code works but does not include the current key or last key of my path string in the search.

I have setup ABC key with additional subkeys in my HKCU registry.  Each contain values and data.  The $Path for the search to begin at is **'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ABC'**

> HKCU\ABC which contains values and its data
>   HKCU\ABC\DEF which contains values and its data
>   HKCU\ABC\DEF\GHI which contains values and its data

My function code (or part of it) looks as follows

```
$objProps = @()

    $Key = Get-ChildItem -Path Registry::$Path -Recurse
    ForEach ($SubKey in $Key) { 
      #$Key = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::$CurRegistryKey
      ForEach ($Prop in $SubKey.Property) {
          if (($SubKey.GetValue($Prop)) -match $ValueDataRegex) {  
            $objProps += @{ 
                Key = $SubKey
                ValueName = $Prop
                ValueData = $SubKey.GetValue($Prop)
            } 
          } 
        }
    } 

    return $objProps
```

It only comes back with results for DEF and GHI. I also want it to search the data in the ABC key. If I use 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\' as my $Path it works but takes a long time as it searches for unnecesary registry keys.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: Hi Mathias.

Thank you for responding.

Version 5.1.14393.1066 but for backward compatibility sake can probably go back to version 4 and/or even 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a second `Get-ChildItem` call before iterating over the results:

```
$Key = @(Get-ChildItem -Path Registry::$Path -Recurse)
$Key += Get-Item Registry::$Path
```

Comment: Ok thank you @Mathias-r-Jessen. I thought there might of been a cmdlet or parameter to include the current key. I guess there isn't one. :-)